# Extjs 3.4 populate grid after ajax call

Tags: json, extjs

Using Extjs 3.4 
My web service respond with a json string: `{"msg":"Some"}`
I want to populate a grid with `Some` .

```
Ext.onReady(function(){

  var store = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
     url: "my/json/url.json",
     fields: [{name:"msg"}]
  });

  function StoreLoadCallback(records, operation, success){
      if (success) {
        console.log(records);   // record is undefined
        alert(records); // show 'undefined'
      } else {
        console.log('error');
      }
  }

  function ajaxSearch_function(){
  var query = Ext.getCmp('search').getValue();
    store.load({
        params: {query: query},
        callback: StoreLoadCallback      
    }); 
  }

  var form = new Ext.FormPanel({
    defaultType: 'textfield',
    items: [{
      fieldLabel: 'search',
      name: 'search',
      id: 'search'
    }],

    buttons: [{
      text: 'Search', handler: ajaxSearch_function
    }]
  });  

  form.render('ajax-search_form');

  var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    store: store,
    columns: [{
        id       :'title',
        header   : 'title', 
        sortable : true, 
        dataIndex: 'title'
      }],
  });

  grid.render('ajax-grid');
});
```

The web service respond well, I have tested with Curl.
The problem is populate the grid with the json response.

Comment: Did you confirm that your JavaScript is making the request to the server correctly?

Comment: Yes, the success boolean is true but the records variable is empty

Comment: For Java web services, you must have proper setters to make proper json. If proper setters are not there, then even if server response is correct, your json will not be created correctly. This may be the problem.

Comment: If I see the response with Curl or with Fiddler I see the correct json string. In my opinion is ext that can`t parse it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say that records variable in callback method is undefined, there is probably a problem with parsing the response. I guess it expects array instead of one single record. Try to change the contents of the json file from `{"msg" : "Some"}` to `[{"msg" : "Some"}]`

After you cross this hurdle (i. e. the response is correctly parsed), I see that your datagrid column refer to "title" rather than "msg". Title is not a member of the store, so the columns will show empty value anyway.

Also, it is not common to start method name with capital letters (except they represent "classes"), so it is kind of nicer to call the method storeLoadCallback instead of StoreLoadCallback.

Comment: The problems are the "title" and the square brackets. With your solution i have resolved.